# Is it possible to get the type of a type field after creating an object?

Tags: scala, types

Is it possible to get the type of a type field after creating an object ?

I would like to do something like this:

```
scala> class A { type T = String }
defined class A

scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@591171

scala> a.T   
<console>:13: error: value T is not a member of A
           a.T
             ^
```

The last

Answer (score 5):

What do you want to do with the type? You can use a type projection in various ways with the class's type (without an instance):

```
scala> class A { type T = String }
defined class A

scala> val x: A#T = "test"
x: java.lang.String = test

scala> def f(b: A#T) = b
f: (a: java.lang.String)java.lang.String
```

Or if you enable `-Ydependent-method-types`, you can get the type member from the instance:

```
scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@6a3de2df

scala> val x: a.T = "test"
x: a.T = test

scala> def f(b: a.T) = b
f: (b: a.T)a.T
```

Scala's reflection API prior to 2.10 doesn't really model types in any clean way, so if you want to "get the type" in some other sense, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

One way is with reflection (since 2.10M4):

```
// with static types
scala> class A { type T = String }
defined class A

scala> import reflect.runtime.{universe => u}
import reflect.runtime.{universe=>u}

scala> val t = u.typeOf[A]
t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = A

scala> val types = t.declarations.filter(_.isType)
types: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(type T)

scala> types.toList.head.typeSignature
res9: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String

// with instances
scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@68d7c870

scala> import reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}
import reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>m}

scala> m.reflect(a).symbol.asType // same type as t
res20: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = A
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible in pre-2.10 (without reflection), too ?

Comment: I don't think so (or at least not in a clean way). JVM-Bytecode does not know type members and there is type erasure. Both do make it really difficult to get the concrete type of a type member.

Comment: @Antoras _Technically_, it is possible. However, not in any standard way, and, honestly, it would be too hard to be worth it when 2.10 is now so close.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: Feel free to write an answer showing us how to read Scala signatures manually... ;)

Comment: @Antoras That's quite easy! First, you import scala-compiler.jar into your project... :-)